# Python subprocess in linux cannot find file while file exist

Tags: python, linux

This bug is driving me crazy.
Error output from my script:

```
>>>Run shell cmd "grep -vw ^# *.blastn | awk $1 != $2 > *matchfile*"
grep: /projects/percid100_2/blastn.outfile: No such file or directory
2
```

I checked the file, it is definitely there.

```
ll /projects/percid100_2/blastn.outfile
-rw-r--r-- 1  users 42633 Apr 17 12:34 /projects/percid100_2/blastn.outfile
```

Previous function:

```
def run_blastn(outdir, outfile):
    """Run blastn under given percent identity """
    print ">>> Run blastn"
    blastnlog = os.path.join(outdir, 'blastn_db_log')
    # make database and run blastn 
    ref = Popen(['cmd1', '-logfile', blastnlog])
    ref.communicate()
    blastn = Popen(['cmd2', '-out', outfile], stderr=PIPE)
```

Function error occurred:

```
def filter_query(infile, matchfile):
    """Filter out self to self hit and no hit"""
    print ">>> Filter query self to self hit and no hit"
    print('>>> Run shell cmd "grep -vw ^# *.blastn | awk $1 != $2 > *matchfile*"')
    grep = Popen(['grep', '-vw', '^#', infile], stdout=PIPE)
    awk = Popen(['awk', '$1 != $2'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    output = awk.communicate()[0]
    grep.communicate()
    if grep.returncode != 0:
        print grep.returncode
        sys.exit()

    with open(matchfile, 'wb') as ofile:
        print 'Write to file %s' % matchfile
        ofile.write(output)
```

Main function:

```
def main():
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not os.path.exists(args.outdir):
        os.makedirs(args.outdir)
    outdir = os.path.abspath(args.outdir)

    bloutfile = 'blastn.outfile'
    path_bloutfile = os.path.join(outdir, bloutfile)

    # filter query seq outfile name 
    matchfile = 'match_file'
    path_matchfile = os.path.join(outdir, matchfile)

    # run blastn 
    run_blastn(outdir, path_bloutfile)
    # filter blastn output gain only matching information 
    filter_query(path_bloutfile, path_matchfile)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

One of the function inputs `infile` is generated from previous function use `subprocess.Popen` calling another program.

My guessing of this issue is the previous command finished and somehow this subprocess call did not recognize the output file of previous function. I have no idea what should I search for solution.

If I try running script couple more times, the script will eventually run successfully.

However, this is not OK.

I tried to use `os.path.abspath()`, no luck on fixing this problem.

Comment: You should be closing `grep.stdout`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I used to have that line. I thought in `Popen`, `Popen.communicate()` would close stdout as well. Therefore, I removed that line. Doesn't `Popen.communicate()` close all file handlers of `subprocess`?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the *exact* value of `infile`? Could there be some hidden characters (I'm thinking a carriage return at the end) that are making `grep` complain?

Comment: Has the previous command actually finished? If you just start up a bunch of `Popen`s and don't `wait`/`communicate`/etc. all of them, they all run at the same time. So the file not exist yet at the time `grep` starts, but by the time you see the error message and test it in the shell, it does.

Comment: Anyway, you need to show us the code that runs that previous command, but I'll bet that's the problem.

Comment: calling `grep.stdout.close()` after starting awk allows grep to receive a SIGPIPE  if awk exits before grep

Comment: If you show us complete code for reproducing this problem, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: `print(repr(['grep', '-vw', '^#', infile]))` would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the problem is in the code you described but haven't showed us, which runs the "previous command" that generates the file that `grep` is looking for.

If you ran that previous command by creating a `Popen`, but then didn't `wait` on it, it'll still be running in the background. If you start up `grep` too quickly, the file may not have been created yet. So you get the error.

Then, it takes a couple seconds for you to go look for the file in the shell, and by that point, it *has* been created. So the error looks baffling.

Or, if you run the program a couple times, eventually it works—either because you get lucky with the timing, or because the file left over from the previous run is found by the new run.

The fix is probably just to add a missing `other_command.communicate()`, but without seeing the other code, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Actually, you are right. While I was editing the post, I realized I did not close the subprocess in my previous function, so I added the line `blastn.communicate()` and the problem disappeared.